# Accessing data from a structure returned by C function in Python using ctypes

Tags: c, python-3.x, ctypes

I know the subject has already been treated, but I've failed to find anything that works for me, so I guess my problem is slightly different from the others.

What I do, basically, is that I use a C function wrapped into a python code using ctypes.
My goal is to compute some quantities in the C function, store them into a single structure, and return the structure in Python where I could read all the different data in the structure.

So :

To define my structure in python, I use :

```
class BITE(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ("lum", ctypes.c_int),
                ("suce", ctypes.c_int)
                ]
```

I compile like that :

```
sub.call(["gcc","-shared","-Wl,-install_name,ex.so","-o","ex.so","-fPIC","ex.c"])


lum = ctypes.CDLL('ex.so')
lum = lum.lum
```

I declare the arguments and result types like this :

```
lum.restype = ctypes.POINTER(BITE)
lum.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float),ctypes.c_int,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float),ctypes.c_int,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float),ctypes.c_int,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float),ctypes.c_int,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float),ctypes.c_float,ctypes.c_float,ctypes.c_float,ctypes.c_float,ctypes.c_float]
```

Then, I call the C function "lum" in the python code

```
out = lum(all the different variables needed)
```

The problem begins here. I have my structure, but impossible to read the data stored in each fields.

A partial solution I found is to do :

```
out = out[0]
```

But then, when doing

```
print(out.suce)
```

I have a segmentation fault 11. DOn't know why. I tried to understand how to used create_string_buffer, but I didn't really understand how it works and what it supposed to do. Moreover, I tried to using as a black box, and still, nothing works.

I also tried some other solutions mentionned in other threads such as using out.contents or something like that, but it has no .contents attributes. Nor out.suce.value, which is also something I saw somewhere during my desperate research.

Of course, I checked in the C code that the structure exists and that each field of the structure exists, and has the right data in it.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide a [mcve].  It's impossible to determine what you are doing wrong if we can't reproduce the issue or at least see the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a C-structure like this :

```
typedef struct _servParams
{
   unsigned short m_uServPort;
   char m_pInetAddr[MAX_LENGTH_OF_IP_ADDRESS];
} ServerParams_t;
```

To use it within ctypes you should create a wrapper like this :

```
class ServerParams_t(Structure):
        _fields_ = [    ("m_uServPort", c_ushort),
                        ("m_pInetAddr", (c_char * 16)) ]
```

Later on inside your python you can use the following snippet :

```
servParams = ServerParams_t()
servParams.m_uServPort = c_ushort(int(port))
servParams.m_pInetAddr = ip.encode()
```

If you need to pass it by value, simply pass `servParams` variable to you api. If you need to pass a pointer use `byref(servParams)`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand how it would work; Sounds to me that servParams = Serverparams_t() will erase the values stored in the structure. And for the to other lines, I don't understand what is port or ip;encode().

Comment: The first line - structure instance is created. Similar to what you have in C code, when defining an instance of this structure.
The 2-nd line - assign a value, defined by local variable called "port" to m_uServPort member
The 3-rd line - assign a string value to "m_pInetAddr" filed. Suppose you have "192.168.0.1" stored in "ip" variable and you would like to assign it to "m_pInetAddr" field - then it's what I've written here.

Comment: Ok thanks, but doing that, I will loose the values previously stored in my structure. I don't want to reassign new values in my structure. I create the structure in my C code. I compute the different values in my C code, and I return the structure with those values in my python code, where I want to have access to those values, calculated in the C code.
If i understand correctly what you said, I reassign new values to each field of my structure. So I loose the result of the calculation of my C code.

Comment: What is you API prototype?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: Hm, what is your C-function declaration ? Give me a snippet how you'd call it

Comment: Okay, let's end the discussino here. I have the feeling I'm wasting your time here. I don't really understand your last question. I mean, my C-function is declared and called as any other C function, so I don't really see what to tell you here. Just a C function that computes some quantities, that's it, and return the structure that I want to keep when I go back to the python code.
Thank you for your answers and your time ;)