# ctypes: extract members of structure returned by C library

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to use ctypes to extract a structure initialized by a C library (see for example: https://tentacles666.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/python-ctypes-dereferencing-a-pointer-to-a-c).

The 'prototype' is:

```
mytype * createMyType();
```

The structure in C is:

```
typedef struct
{
        int              a;
        void             *b;
}mytype;
```

from which in python(3)! I have created a ctypes structure thus:

```
class mytype(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", ctypes.c_int),
               ("b", ctypes.POINTER(None))]
```

The C call is:

```
mytype*myinstance = createMyType()
```

The Python call is as follows:

```
import ctypes
f=mylib.createMyType
f.argtypes=()
f.restype=(ctypes.POINTER(mytype),)
x=f()
```

The problem is that `x` seems to be an integer; how do I interpret this as a pointer, or - as required - extract the members of `x` themselves?

How do I access and then modify `x.a` and `x.b`?

[See also [Accessing data from a structure returned by C function in Python using ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883395/accessing-data-from-a-structure-returned-by-c-function-in-python-using-ctypes), which led nowhere]

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but I think one step would be to change the type of `b` to `ctypes.c_void_p`

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it may help anyway: If you have control over the C code as well, I found it much easier to do all allocations on the Python side, and then pass pointers to the C code to populate the data.  In this case you can create a `mytype` in Python and pass a pointer to it to `createMyType()`, instead of returning a pointer to newly allocated data from C.  This way, you can make use of Python's garbage collector for everything, which makes things a lot easier.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately no access to the C inside the library :\ The furthest I've made it so far is a segfault 11, which is presumably related to garbage collection/ownership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly you need `c_void_p` for the void* and must dereference the return with `.contents`.

Here's a working example (Windows)...

**Edit**: I added an example of casting the void pointer member.

**test.h**

```
#ifdef EXPORT
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

typedef struct
{
        int a;
        void* b;
} mytype;

API mytype* createMyType();
API void destroyMyType(mytype* p);
```

**test.c**

```
#define EXPORT
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

API mytype* createMyType()
{
    int* tmp;
    mytype* p = malloc(sizeof(mytype));
    p->a = 5;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *tmp = 123;
    p->b = tmp;
    printf("%d %p\n",p->a,p->b);
    return p;
}

API void destroyMyType(mytype* p)
{
    free(p->b);
    free(p);
}
```

**test.py**

```
from ctypes import *

class mytype(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('a',c_int),
                ('b',c_void_p)]

test = CDLL('test')
createMyType = test.createMyType
createMyType.argtypes = None
createMyType.restype = POINTER(mytype)
destroyMyType = test.destroyMyType
destroyMyType.argtypes = POINTER(mytype),
destroyMyType.restype = None

t = createMyType()
print('t is',t)
print('t.a is',t.contents.a)
print('t.b is',hex(t.contents.b))
b = cast(t.contents.b,POINTER(c_int))
print('*b is',b.contents)
destroyMyType(t)
```

**Output**: Note that the void* b address output in the C code matches the integer returned by `t.contents.b`.  The `cast` turns that integer into a `POINTER(c_int)` where the contents can be extracted.

```
5 00000216C0E2A5D0
t is <__main__.LP_mytype object at 0x00000216C30C4A48>
t.a is 5
t.b is 0x216c0e2a5d0
*b is c_long(123)
```

Comment: So I still have this problem that for my code the `t` equivalent is an integer (even though I've defined `restype` as a `POINTER`). Does that mean my prototype is down wrong, or something else?  `<class 'int'> 1372168` Is my `t` an address? How do I convert it to a `POINTER`? Thanks!

Comment: @jztl2 The prototype is correct. `c_void_p` doesn't point to anything so ctypes just returns the address. You can initialize a concrete pointer type with that address.

Comment: How do I force initialization to the address rather than to an integer that happens to represent it?

Comment: If I do `ptr=ctypes.cast(t, ctypes.POINTER(mytype))`, I get for `print(ptr)`: `<__main__.LP_mytype object at 0x1031f5488>`, but then a segfault 11 whenever I attempt something like `ptr.contents` :\ Are the library-allocated contents inaccessible to me, or do they - or their address - need copying in some fashion?

Comment: @jtlz2 Are you using your code in your question?  The `.restype` there isn't declared correctly.  You have a 1-tuple of `f.restype=(ctypes.POINTER(mytype),)`.  It should be `f.restype = ctypes.POINTER(mytype)` as in my example code.  You don't need to cast it.

Comment: @jtlz2 In the case of the `c_void_p` type of the `b` member where it returns an integer, you *can* just do `cast(t.contents.b,POINTER(c_int))` if that void pointer happens to point to an integer.  I'll update my answer with that example.

Comment: Yep, fixed. Having problems compiling your example (am on macOS) - what compile line are you using? Huge thanks.

Comment: @jtlz2 I'm using the Visual Studio compiler on Windows.  `cl /LD test.c`.  `/LD` creates a DLL.  If my answer is useful, consider upvoting or accepting :^)

Comment: Don't worry I will of course :) Just need to get it working on macOS... Do you have any idea why I am getting back `<class 'int'>` for `t` even when I set `.restype=ctypes.POINTER(mytype)`?

Comment: @jtlz2 Not without seeing a reproducible example :)

Comment: Any chance you could post your DLL somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166630/discussion-between-jtlz2-and-mark-tolonen).