# ctypes: Modifying an array inside a structure passed as an argument to library function

Tags: python, ctypes

[Please note that this is a `ctypes`-specific question.]

Following on from [ctypes: extract members of structure returned by C library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175959/ctypes-extract-members-of-structure-returned-by-c-library), I am trying to use `ctypes` in `python3` to arrange for a DLL (for which I do not have access to the source code) to populate an array inside a structure passed as an argument to a particular function.

The C prototype for the function is

```
int func(a * aa, b * bb, c * cc);
```

and the C structures are as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
        int              a1;
}a;

typedef struct
{
        int              b1;
        unsigned char    *b2;

}b;

typedef struct
{
        int              c1;
        unsigned char    *c2;
}c;
```

When I call func on the python side, i.e.

```
func.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(a),\
                    ctypes.POINTER(b),
                    ctypes.POINTER(c))
func.restype=ctypes.c_int
status=dll.func(aa,bb,cc)
```

The `status` is returned as `1` rather than `0`, so is presumably not successful.

I cannot make `bb` a pointer because I get:

```
ValueError: ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled
```

I am unsure:

1. How to initialize `bb` from a python-side bytearray;
2. if there's an issue modifying the memory for `bb` (which is the output array);
3. whether to set `aa`, `bb`, `cc` on the python side or the C side (which does have routines for initialization); and,
4. whether argtypes should be `POINTERS`, and whether `aa`, `bb` and `cc` should be passed using `ctypes.pointer()`, `ctypes.byref()` or simply as themselves.

All help much appreciated.

Comment: Too many unknown here. Please post the *Python* code. "*populate an array inside a structure*" What does that mean? The array must also be allocated? How would the *C* code know its length (when to stop if the array is too short)? There are 3 arguments passed to the func. The *.dll* code is unavailable, but its documentation should be.

Comment: Referring back to my answer in your referenced question [ctypes: extract members of structure returned by C library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175959/ctypes-extract-members-of-structure-returned-by-c-library), can you make a similar [mcve] to demonstrate what the DLL you want to call does?  There isn't enough information here and no way to reproduce the error you report.